# Exception deploying Spring Boot app locally with Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

I get the following error whenever I run: 'heroku local web'

> .springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '$PORT'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$PORT"

My Procfile looks like this:

> web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar  build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar

I am able to deploy to heroku, but I would like to be able to run locally to verify deployment before deploying remotely.

I have a windows PORT system environment variable, and a Heroku config variable set with 'heroku config:set PORT=8080.' I set each of these independently with no change in the above error. Anyone know why I getting this?

Comment: I have also tried 'heroku local web -p 8080' and get the same exception. A workaround is to replace '$PORT' with '8080' in the Procfile, but I would rather not do this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you need to reference environment variables like `%PORT%` instead of the `$` notation, which is *nix specific.

To fix this, you should create a `Procfile.windows` file with these contents:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=%PORT% -jar build\libs\gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
```

And then run this command:

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

Comment: I was looking exactly for this. Thank you very much !